# How do I solve 'npm i' building error in expo project

Tags: react-native, expo

I tried to run the expo project.
But I had this error.

```
PS F:\Data(D)\Dev\Projects\Mobile\expo-cli> npm i
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: eslint-config-universe@10.0.0
npm ERR! Found: prettier@2.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/prettier
npm ERR!   prettier@"^2.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer prettier@">=2.0.0" from eslint-plugin-prettier@4.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier
npm ERR!     eslint-plugin-prettier@"^4.0.0" from eslint-config-universe@10.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/eslint-config-universe
npm ERR!       eslint-config-universe@"^10.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional prettier@">=2.4" from eslint-config-universe@10.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-config-universe
npm ERR!   eslint-config-universe@"^10.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: prettier@3.2.5
npm ERR!   peerOptional prettier@">=2.4" from eslint-config-universe@10.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-universe
npm ERR!     eslint-config-universe@"^10.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-14T15_59_28_773Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

What should I do?
I am a beginner so I want to anybody help me.

I want build project with no Error.

Comment: Try to solve the conflicts on your package.json or just try ```nom install --legacy-peer-deps```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. As you can see I am a beginner. So I need someone's help. Can you help me? If you can, please leave your telegram info. Thank you.

Comment: my telegram info is Joy840629.
Please ping me. Thank you...